# How do I fit a sine curve to my data with pylab and numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, curve-fitting

I am trying to show that economies follow a relatively sinusoidal growth pattern. I am building a python simulation to show that even when we let some degree of randomness take hold, we can still produce something relatively sinusoidal.

I am happy with the data I'm producing, but now I'd like to find some way to get a sine graph that pretty closely matches the data. I know you can do polynomial fit, but can you do sine fit?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use the [least-square optimization](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html) function in scipy to fit any arbitrary function to another. In case of fitting a sin function, the 3 parameters to fit are the offset ('a'), amplitude ('b') and the phase ('c').

As long as you provide a reasonable first guess of the parameters, the optimization should converge well.Fortunately for a sine function, first estimates of 2 of these are easy: the offset can be estimated by taking the mean of the data and the amplitude via the RMS (3*standard deviation/sqrt(2)).

Note: as a later edit, frequency fitting has also been added. This does not work very well (can lead to extremely poor fits). Thus, use at your discretion, my advise would be to not use frequency fitting unless frequency error is smaller than a few percent.

This leads to the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
import pylab as plt

N = 1000 # number of data points
t = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, N)
f = 1.15247 # Optional!! Advised not to use
data = 3.0*np.sin(f*t+0.001) + 0.5 + np.random.randn(N) # create artificial data with noise

guess_mean = np.mean(data)
guess_std = 3*np.std(data)/(2**0.5)/(2**0.5)
guess_phase = 0
guess_freq = 1
guess_amp = 1

# we'll use this to plot our first estimate. This might already be good enough for you
data_first_guess = guess_std*np.sin(t+guess_phase) + guess_mean

# Define the function to optimize, in this case, we want to minimize the difference
# between the actual data and our "guessed" parameters
optimize_func = lambda x: x[0]*np.sin(x[1]*t+x[2]) + x[3] - data
est_amp, est_freq, est_phase, est_mean = leastsq(optimize_func, [guess_amp, guess_freq, guess_phase, guess_mean])[0]

# recreate the fitted curve using the optimized parameters
data_fit = est_amp*np.sin(est_freq*t+est_phase) + est_mean

# recreate the fitted curve using the optimized parameters

fine_t = np.arange(0,max(t),0.1)
data_fit=est_amp*np.sin(est_freq*fine_t+est_phase)+est_mean

plt.plot(t, data, '.')
plt.plot(t, data_first_guess, label='first guess')
plt.plot(fine_t, data_fit, label='after fitting')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Edit: I assumed that you know the number of periods in the sine-wave. If you don't, it's somewhat trickier to fit. You can try and guess the number of periods by manual plotting and try and optimize it as your 6th parameter.

Comment: This solution, though accepted by OP, seems to skip over the trickiest part: the _frequency_ `f` as in `y = Amplitude*sin(frequency*x +Phase) + Offset`.  How well does this method work if `f` is unknown?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use scipy's curve_fit function? I'm guessing there's something about that initial guess and/or curve_fit making assumptions about the function.

Comment: I think the order of initial parameter values you provide the function is wrong. What about `est_a, est_b, est_c = leastsq(optimize_func, [guess_b, guess_a, guess_c])[0]`? For clarity, I would suggest replacing _a with _offset, _b with _amp, and _c with _phase everywhere and use increasing order of x[i] in your lambda.

Answer (score 106):

Here is a parameter-free fitting function `fit_sin()` that does not require manual guess of frequency:

```
import numpy, scipy.optimize

def fit_sin(tt, yy):
    '''Fit sin to the input time sequence, and return fitting parameters "amp", "omega", "phase", "offset", "freq", "period" and "fitfunc"'''
    tt = numpy.array(tt)
    yy = numpy.array(yy)
    ff = numpy.fft.fftfreq(len(tt), (tt[1]-tt[0]))   # assume uniform spacing
    Fyy = abs(numpy.fft.fft(yy))
    guess_freq = abs(ff[numpy.argmax(Fyy[1:])+1])   # excluding the zero frequency "peak", which is related to offset
    guess_amp = numpy.std(yy) * 2.**0.5
    guess_offset = numpy.mean(yy)
    guess = numpy.array([guess_amp, 2.*numpy.pi*guess_freq, 0., guess_offset])

    def sinfunc(t, A, w, p, c):  return A * numpy.sin(w*t + p) + c
    popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(sinfunc, tt, yy, p0=guess)
    A, w, p, c = popt
    f = w/(2.*numpy.pi)
    fitfunc = lambda t: A * numpy.sin(w*t + p) + c
    return {"amp": A, "omega": w, "phase": p, "offset": c, "freq": f, "period": 1./f, "fitfunc": fitfunc, "maxcov": numpy.max(pcov), "rawres": (guess,popt,pcov)}
```

The initial frequency guess is given by the peak frequency in the frequency domain using FFT. The fitting result is almost perfect assuming there is only one dominant frequency (other than the zero frequency peak).

```
import pylab as plt

N, amp, omega, phase, offset, noise = 500, 1., 2., .5, 4., 3
#N, amp, omega, phase, offset, noise = 50, 1., .4, .5, 4., .2
#N, amp, omega, phase, offset, noise = 200, 1., 20, .5, 4., 1
tt = numpy.linspace(0, 10, N)
tt2 = numpy.linspace(0, 10, 10*N)
yy = amp*numpy.sin(omega*tt + phase) + offset
yynoise = yy + noise*(numpy.random.random(len(tt))-0.5)

res = fit_sin(tt, yynoise)
print( "Amplitude=%(amp)s, Angular freq.=%(omega)s, phase=%(phase)s, offset=%(offset)s, Max. Cov.=%(maxcov)s" % res )

plt.plot(tt, yy, "-k", label="y", linewidth=2)
plt.plot(tt, yynoise, "ok", label="y with noise")
plt.plot(tt2, res["fitfunc"](tt2), "r-", label="y fit curve", linewidth=2)
plt.legend(loc="best")
plt.show()
```

The result is good even with high noise:

> Amplitude=1.00660540618, Angular freq.=2.03370472482, phase=0.360276844224, offset=3.95747467506, Max. Cov.=0.0122923578658

[image: With noise]
[image: Low frequency]
[image: High frequency]

Comment: Dear unsym

I tried to run your code but unfortunately I receive the following message:

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer 

When I try to plot the function. Do you have any idea to solve this?

Comment: I have just run the code verbatim as is and it worked without any error, using python 3.6 (in a jupyter notebook with matplotlib "inline" plotting turned on in the notebook)

Comment: what is the technique called for estimating amplitude used in this code?

Comment: @unsym, can you give a short description of what each parameter returned means? or a relevant reference?

Comment: small extension to this. if you want to fix/set the period to be some particular value e.x period = number of points **this means the sin function will be 1 continuous arc across your data**. you can find the b value `b = 2*pi / p` then curve_fit to `a*sin(b*x+c)+d` replacing b by the value you calculated.

Answer (score 19):

More userfriendly to us is the function curvefit. Here an example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import pylab as plt

N = 1000 # number of data points
t = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, N)
data = 3.0*np.sin(t+0.001) + 0.5 + np.random.randn(N) # create artificial data with noise

guess_freq = 1
guess_amplitude = 3*np.std(data)/(2**0.5)
guess_phase = 0
guess_offset = np.mean(data)

p0=[guess_freq, guess_amplitude,
    guess_phase, guess_offset]

# create the function we want to fit
def my_sin(x, freq, amplitude, phase, offset):
    return np.sin(x * freq + phase) * amplitude + offset

# now do the fit
fit = curve_fit(my_sin, t, data, p0=p0)

# we'll use this to plot our first estimate. This might already be good enough for you
data_first_guess = my_sin(t, *p0)

# recreate the fitted curve using the optimized parameters
data_fit = my_sin(t, *fit[0])

plt.plot(data, '.')
plt.plot(data_fit, label='after fitting')
plt.plot(data_first_guess, label='first guess')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: @IceArdor: Can you add a working code example of the solvers you propose?

Comment: @Vasco what if I have a x_train of m*n shape and y_train of m*1 shape then in that case i am receiving this error: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (38563,54) (38563,) . So what should i do now?

Comment: @Vasco Can you show me some example or if can post your answer here with some example code it would be very helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57027040/regressing-periodic-data-with-sklearn

Answer (score 10):

The current methods to fit a sin curve to a given data set require a first guess of the parameters, followed by an interative process. This is a non-linear regression problem.

A different method consists in transforming the non-linear regression to a linear regression thanks to a convenient integral equation. Then, there is no need for initial guess and no need for iterative process : the fitting is directly obtained.

In case of the function `y = a + r*sin(w*x+phi)` or `y=a+b*sin(w*x)+c*cos(w*x)`, see pages 35-36 of the paper `"Régression sinusoidale"` published on [Scribd](http://www.scribd.com/JJacquelin/documents)

In case of the function `y = a + p*x + r*sin(w*x+phi)` : pages 49-51 of the chapter "Mixed linear and sinusoidal regressions".

In case of more complicated functions, the general process is explained in the chapter `"Generalized sinusoidal regression"` pages 54-61, followed by a numerical example `y = r*sin(w*x+phi)+(b/x)+c*ln(x)`, pages 62-63

Comment: By chance, do you happen to have a reference for damped sinusoids' transformation?

Comment: +1 this looks very interesting, the problem is that the reference is in French. Does anyone know some English resource (could be anything from blog post / paper / code) that illustrates the approach in a bit more detail? If converting to linear regression is indeed possible, I'm wondering why this approach is not more popular?

Comment: Ah I've found a great resource: [scikit-guess](https://github.com/madphysicist/scikit-guess). Not only does it provide an implementation, it also comes with an entire [translation](https://scikit-guess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/appendices/references.html) of the paper.

Comment: @nopeva . I will try to answer to your question. But it is difficult to avoid confusion between the various cases and examples. In order to avoid misunderstanding I think  it should be better that you open a new question specific of your actual problem : With an example of data and with the function to be fitted. So I could answer with the details of calculus.

Comment: @nopeva . The full answer to your question (with the data) about the fitting of the sum of two sinusoidal functions is ready to be posted. But I cannot find where your question is now. Is your question closed or deleted ?

Comment: @nopeva. Good new : With your data the quality of fitting using the method with integral equation is almost the same as using usual non-linear regression. But of course without requiring initial guessed values which is the advantage compared to iterative non-linear regression.

Comment: @JJacquelin thanks for taking the time to find a solution. I have reopened the question.

Answer (score 6):

All the above answers are based on curve fitting, and most use an iterative method - they all work very nicely, but I wanted to add a different approach using an FFT.  Here, we transform the data, set all but the peak frequency to zero and then do the inverse transform.  Note, that you probably want to remove the data mean (and detrend) before doing the FFT and then you can add those back in after.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

# fake data

N = 1000 # number of data points
t = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, N)
f = 1.05
data = 3.0*np.sin(f*t+0.001) + np.random.randn(N) # create artificial data with noise

# FFT...
mfft=np.fft.fft(data)
imax=np.argmax(np.absolute(mfft))
mask=np.zeros_like(mfft)
mask[[imax]]=1
mfft*=mask
fdata=np.fft.ifft(mfft)


plt.plot(t, data, '.')
plt.plot(t, fdata,'.', label='FFT')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It should be noted that the FFT requires evenly sampled data points, curve fitting does not.

Comment: Yes good point, thanks for pointing that out. I suppose one could resample the data prior to the fft

Answer (score 2):

Fitting a sine curve with unknown amplitude, frequency and phase is a non-linear problem. If the frequency is known, then it can be solved with linear least-squares as other mentioned.

When frequency is unknown, the optimal solution in case of a sine wave in white gaussian noise is described in the classical book by Kay: *Fundamentals of Statistical Signal Processing: Estimation Theory* (p.193). It requires searching for the frequency minimizing the sum of the squares of the residuals, while solving the linear problem for amplitude and phase at each step.

There is a python library called [pyestimate](https://github.com/alexishumblet/pyestimate) which implements this solution. It can fit a noisy sine wave:

```py
#!pip install pyestimate
from pyestimate import sin_param_estimate
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# define a signal to be fitted
n = np.arange(100)
s = 1.234 * np.cos(2*np.pi*0.0345*n + np.pi/7)
# add some noise
x = s + np.random.normal(scale=0.5, size=len(n))

# fit amplitude, frequency and phase
A,f,phi = sin_param_estimate(x)

# plot result
plt.plot(s, '-', label='original sine')
plt.plot(x, '.', label='noisy input data')
plt.plot(A*np.cos(2*np.pi*f*n+phi), 'r--', label='fitted sine')
plt.legend()
```

[image: Plot of result]

[pyestimate](https://github.com/alexishumblet/pyestimate) also implements fitting of a sum of sine waves.

**Unevenly spaced data**

In case the data is unevenly spaced, the same method can be used (searching for the frequency minimizing the sum of the squares of the residuals, while solving the linear problem for amplitude and phase at each step). However, in this case, you have to provide an estimate of the maximum expected frequency. Here is an example:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize

N = 100 # number of input samples
f = 327 # frequency to be estimated in Hz
A = 1.0 # amplitude to be estimated
phi = np.pi/4 # phase to be estimated
sigma = 0.5 # standard deviation of WGN to add to sine

t = np.logspace(0, np.log10(1+2/f), N)-1 # Unevenly spaced time vector
fmax = 1000 # maximum expected frequency, must be provided for unevenly spaced data

# generate input signal
s = A * np.cos(2*np.pi*f*t+phi) # original signal
w = np.random.default_rng(seed=0).normal(scale=sigma, size=N) # white gaussian noise
x = s+w # input signal for estimation: sine + noise

# find frequency with optimization
def J_func(f):
    f = f[0]
    co = np.cos(2*np.pi*f*t)
    si = np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t)
    H = np.vstack([co, si]).T
    return (-x.T @ H @ np.linalg.inv(H.T @ H) @ H.T @ x)
f_hat = optimize.brute(J_func, ((1e-12, fmax),), Ns=1000, finish=optimize.fmin)[0]

# solve linear problem to get amplitude and phase
co = np.cos(2*np.pi*f_hat*t)
si = np.sin(2*np.pi*f_hat*t)
H = np.vstack([co, si]).T
alpha_hat = np.linalg.inv(H.T @ H) @ H.T @ x
A_hat = np.linalg.norm(alpha_hat)
phi_hat = np.arctan2(-alpha_hat[1], alpha_hat[0])

# reconstruct signal from estimated parameters
s_hat = A_hat * np.cos(2*np.pi*f_hat*t+phi_hat) # estimated signal

# plot result
plt.plot(t, s, '-', linewidth=3.0, label='original signal')
plt.plot(t, x, '.', label='corrupted (input) signal')
plt.plot(t, s_hat, 'k--', label='estimated signal')
plt.xlabel('$t$')
plt.ylabel('$x[t]$')
plt.title('Sinusoidal parameters estimation')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image: Sinusoidal fit with unevenly spaced samples]

Comment: It looks like `pyestimate` can only fit data with uniform spacing in x?

Comment: @astroboylrx, indeed pyestimate assumes uniform sampling. However, the same method can be used with unevenly spaced data. I have updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 1):

If you already know the frequency, you can do a linear fit, which is computationally more efficient than the nonlinear fitting methods. As @JJacquelin points out, no initial guesses are required.

Explicitly, you'd fit  `y=a+b*sin(x)+c*sin(x)` to the data.
Note, this is equivalent to `A*sin(x+phi)`, by trig identities. However, this is expressed in a way that's linear in the fit parameters (though not in x,y). Thus we can use a linear fit in python.

Just pretend that `x1 = sin(x)` and `x2 = cos(x)` are inputs, use a linear fitting function on `y = a + b* x1 + c* x2`

To do that use

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
reg = LinearRegression()

x= # your x values list
y = # your y values list
X = np.column_stack((np.sin(x), np.cos(x)))

reg.fit(X, y)
```

you can access the fit parameters by:

```
a = reg.intercept_
b = reg.coef_[0]
c = reg.coef_[1]
```