# Applying bounds to Scipy Optimise Curvefit

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit a simple sinewave to data and applying bounds to help constrain the fit.

I am using the 2nd answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716302/how-do-i-fit-a-sine-curve-to-my-data-with-pylab-and-numpy) which is working perfectly, however when I apply bounds as per convention, e.g.:

```
def fit_sin(tt, yy):
    import scipy.optimize
    import numpy as np
    '''
    Fit sin to the input time sequence, and return dict of fitting parameters:
    "amp", "omega", "phase", "offset", "freq", "period" and "fitfunc"
    '''
    tt = np.array(tt)
    yy = np.array(yy)
    ff = np.fft.fftfreq(len(tt), (tt[1]-tt[0]))   # assume uniform spacing
    Fyy = abs(np.fft.fft(yy))
    guess_freq = abs(ff[np.argmax(Fyy[1:])+1])   # excluding the zero frequency "peak", which is related to offset
    guess_amp = np.std(yy) * 2.**0.5
    guess_offset = np.mean(yy)
    guess = np.array([guess_amp, 2.*np.pi*guess_freq, 0., guess_offset])

    def sinfunc(t, A, w, p, c):  return A * np.sin(w*t + p) + c
    boundary = ([-np.inf, -np.inf, -np.pi, -np.inf],[np.inf, np.inf, np.pi, np.inf])
    popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(sinfunc, tt, yy, p0=guess, bounds=boundary)
    A, w, p, c = popt
    f = w/(2.*np.pi)
    fitfunc = lambda t: A * np.sin(w*t + p) + c
    return {"amp": A, "omega": w, "phase": p, "offset": c, "freq": f, "period": 1./f, "fitfunc": fitfunc, "maxcov": np.max(pcov), "rawres": (guess,popt,pcov)}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: The maximum number of function evaluations is exceeded.
```

If I set the bounds to infinity and I change the boundary line to simply,

```
boundary = ([-np.inf, -np.inf, -np.inf, -np.inf],[np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf])
```

the function works.

To test the function you can do:

```
import pylab as plt

N, amp, omega, phase, offset, noise = 500, 1., 2., .5, 4., 3
#N, amp, omega, phase, offset, noise = 50, 1., .4, .5, 4., .2
#N, amp, omega, phase, offset, noise = 200, 1., 20, .5, 4., 1
tt = numpy.linspace(0, 10, N)
tt2 = numpy.linspace(0, 10, 10*N)
yy = amp*numpy.sin(omega*tt + phase) + offset
yynoise = yy + noise*(numpy.random.random(len(tt))-0.5)

res = fit_sin(tt, yynoise)
print( "Amplitude=%(amp)s, Angular freq.=%(omega)s, phase=%(phase)s, offset=%(offset)s, Max. Cov.=%(maxcov)s" % res )

plt.plot(tt, yy, "-k", label="y", linewidth=2)
plt.plot(tt, yynoise, "ok", label="y with noise")
plt.plot(tt2, res["fitfunc"](tt2), "r-", label="y fit curve", linewidth=2)
plt.legend(loc="best")
plt.show()
```

In particular I am just trying to constrain the phase `p` of the fit to be between `-np.pi` and `np.pi`, the others can be infinity.

The actual data I'm using this function on is clean and the fit is quick and really accurate, but it's sometimes fitting the phase a whole cycle 'out of step' when the data starts at or near +/- `np.pi`, it will fit it `2*np.pi` out phase.

I can't manually catch this either as it's fitting to many thousands of data sets and I'm looking at relative phase differences between them all.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is the `boundary` line that is giving you troubles? If I use this: `boundary = ([0.0, 0.0, -np.pi, -100.0],[10.0, 1000.0, np.pi, 100.0])` the code works as expected. Note that the fitting algorithm is different depending on whether you provide bounds or not. As a side note, `import ...` statements are typically outside of the function, the docstring is enclosed with triple `"""` double-quotes, and immediately follows the function definition.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've just found the issue: the fit was actually fitting to negative values of amplitude e.g. `-100` instead of `100`, and then that mean the fitted phase value was forced to be `pi` larger.

Comment: The code in the question right now works well. Hence, unless you also include the code that was causing you troubles, I am unsure it would be of any value to future readers.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it, for a particular data set causing me trouble, my function was fitting negative amplitudes which then forced my phase value to be `np.pi` larger than anticipated.

I'll leave this answer here for anyone having similar troubles with sine-wave fitting!